# Iterating through blobs in Azure SDK v12

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am upgrading a web app to use Azure SDK v 12.10

Before this, I was grabbing all the blobs in a virtual path from the container into a list and iterating through them.

```
var results = await blobContainer.
                ListBlobsSegmentedAsync("publicfiles/images/" + customer.AzureFolderName, true, BlobListingDetails.All, 100, blobContinuationToken, null, null);
            // Get the value of the continuation token returned by the listing call.
            blobContinuationToken = results.ContinuationToken;

            foreach (var item in results.Results)
            {
                var filename = GetFileNameFromBlobUri(item.Uri, customer.AzureFolderName);
                var img = new EvaluationImage
                {
                    ImageUrl = item.Uri.ToString(),
                    ImageCaption = GetCaptionFromFilename(filename),
                    IsPosterImage = filename.Contains("poster"),
                    ImagesForCompany = customer.CompanyName
                };

                images.Add(img);
            }
```

All I can find from googling how to do so in the new SDK, yields this

```
await foreach (BlobItem blob in blobContainer.GetBlobsAsync(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.None, $"publicfiles/images/{customer.AzureFolderName}"))
```

The problem is the "blob" variable (BlobItem) has minimal useable properties, for example, I need the Uri which was available before. The "blob" variable in prior versions had a multitude of useable properties. Is there some other type (not BlobItem) that has these properties that I'm not finding in my searching?

I don't see anything useable in BlobTraits or BlobStates either that change this.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of [`Metadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobitem.metadata?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobItem_Metadata)?

Comment: Or [`Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobitem.properties?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobItem_Properties)?

Comment: Which SDK exactly name and version you're using? I've just tested NuGet package Azure.Storage.Blobs (version 12.8.0) + .NET Core 3.1 Console App and method ListBlobsSegmentedAsync() is still available as is in your code along with URI property. Please double check the NuGet package and version.

Comment: Metadata nor Properties have any of the needed properties. I am using Azure SDK v 12.10.0 beta 2 Azure.Storage.Blobs

Comment: Evandro...Im using .Net 6 preview, not 3.1 and there is no ListBlobsSegmentedAsync method on BlobClient, which is what's used in v12, that's a v11 method of CloudBobContainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as straight forward to get the URI of the blob in SDK version 12.x. When you get a [`BlobItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobitem?view=azure-dotnet) as part of listing result, you will need to create a [`BlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient?view=azure-dotnet) object out of it and then you will be able to get the URI of the blob.

Here's the sample code to do so:

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(container);
var listingResult = containerClient.GetBlobsAsync();
await foreach (var blobItem in listingResult)
{
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);
    Uri blobUri = blobClient.Uri;
    //Do something with the URI...
}
```

Code above makes use of [`Azure.Storage.Blobs (12.9.1)`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/12.9.1) SDK.

Comment: I only really needed the filename, and I now get it from the blob.Name, but this is very helpful